# How can I persist my compile ring

Tags: persistence

I would like to persist my compile-ring, by which I mean the history of compile commands I use, between emacs sessions.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```el
(setq savehist-additional-variables '(compile-command))
(savehist-mode)
```